# Function return type validation by compiler

Tags: c++

I read in Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel that when a C++ compiler encounters a function it decorates it's name using it's name and arguments. 
For a function, int func(char ch); it would decorate it's name as _func_char It doesn't use the return type.

In that case,
In the below program how does the compiler complain "invalid conversion from int to const char*" when it has not stored the return type during function name decoration? Can anyone please clarify?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int func()
{
    int i = 5;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    string str = func();
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B

Comment: Name mangling is just for *linking* - the compiler still knows everything it needs to know about functions within a compilation unit.

Comment: Two functions can't exist with the same arguments but different return types and so it's not necessary to mangle-in the return type.

Answer (score 5):

Symbol (not just functions) name mangling comes into play at the linking stage. You're getting a compiler error.

The compiler doesn't see the mangled name. It just sees you have a function called `func` that returns an `int` and takes no parameters, and so can tell you your code is illegal.

Answer (score 5):

This is an compilation error.
Compiler checks for the validity of the C++ program as per the C++ Standard specification.

> **Why does the compiler report an error here?**

Because compiler ***can see*** that return type of the function is `int`and it is being used to initialize a variable of the type `std::string` and there is no valid implicit conversion for it.

Note that the language is designed in such a way it allows the compiler to do these kind of type checking, C++ is a ***[statically typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language#Static_versus_dynamic_typing)***.